# How to create a countdown inside Android FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, runtimeexception, android-looper

I'm trying to create countdown inside FirebaseMessagingService like this:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
long timerLeft = 5000;

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
startTimer();
}

  public void startTimer() {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerLeft, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerLeft = millisUntilFinished;
            Log.d("timerleft: ",""+timerLeft);
        }
        public void onFinish() {

            timerLeft=10000;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

But when I recieve message I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always listen to the log and call `Looper.prepare()` before creating `new CountDownTimer`, but I would advise you to use some scheduling mechanism, e.g. `WorkManager` or `AlarmManager`. that depends on what do you want to achieve after counter finish

edit due to comments:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    long lastMsgTimestamp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
            getLong("lastMsgTimestamp", 0L);

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = getPendingIntent(this);
    if(lastMsgTimestamp + 5000 >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        mgr.cancel(pi);
    }
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, pi);

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().
            putLong("lastMsgTimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
}

private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctx){
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, FiveSecsBroadcast.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i, 0);
}
```

`FiveSecsBroadcast` is a `BroadcastReceiver` which will fire after 5 secs (`onReceive` method). you may pass some data using `Bundle` extras in `Intent`

Comment: Hi, tnks for answer, I use Looper.prepare(). Now I haven't error but I can't see `Log.d("timerleft: ",""+timerLeft);`. this CountDown doesn't start. 
I want that if I recieve first message, a countdown begins. If within 5 seconds I receive a further message something happens, otherwise another happens.

Comment: you may need to use `Looper.loop()` also but remeber that when second msg will arrive then new instance of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` may be created and inside it there will be no `CountDownTimer` running. I would advise you to store some data and leave first service for killing. when new/another instance will be created then check when previous message was delivered. fastest way would be to use `SharedPreferences`, check out edit of my ans

Comment: This doesn't work, because `if(lastMsgTimestamp + 5000 >= System.currentTimeMillis())` will only be called if a new message arrives. I want that "
if no messages arrive within 5 seconds" then do somethings..

Comment: Infact, my idea was to use countdown that start when one message arrive, if another message arrive in 5 seconds, then the countdown restart again.. if No messages arrives within 5 seconds, then something happends

Comment: I've wrote below snippet that you have to use `AlarmManager` or any other scheduling mechanism... edited answer with some sample - when msgs are comming more often that 5 secs then `cancel` (previously set) alarm will be called. after that set (another/new) alarm for firing after 5 secs. do your job in `BroadcastReceiver`